# Align the paragraph according to the page width in HTML,CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a label and I have add some paragraph for the label. So I tried to do the same in my script but what happens here is paragraph is not aligned properly. I want the paragraph to be aligned to 3/4th of the page. So that I can save the below space.

```html
<html>

<head>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--Stylesheets-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--JS-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="grey_text text-center">Details</h2>
  <div class="container col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="container col-md-offset-1">
      <div id="form">
        <form>
          <fieldset>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-display">
              <label class="col-md-8" for="comments:">Added comments:</label>
              <div>
                <p>Respected Sir/Madam, My name is nnnnn. I have completed my Bachelor's degree from this college in the field of Engineering. I love problem-solving and reducing the complexity of issues, this pushed me towards Software technology. I have interned as a test engineer at a firm called vvvvvvvv and learned fundamental about testing. I always want to learn about new technologies and want to apply them in real life, which is why I feel I am suitable for this internship. The project's link which I have worked the respective Github repository link/Google drive link can be found in my resume. I am attaching my resume, certificate, and Linkedin profile for your reference. Looking forward to hearing from you soon. Thanks and regards, nnnnnnn LinkedIn profile: https://www.linkedin.com/in/nnnnnn/</p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If I remove the Bootstrap and jQuery library from the script the paragraph looks good. But I need those Bootstrap and ajax library since I am using jQuery, Bootstrap style in the remaining program and the other filed. I tried

```
text-align: justify;text-justify: inter-word;
```

by including it in the `<p>` tag. By including word-wrap also it didn't work.

What I need here is the paragraph should display for the width so that it looks nice.

Comment: You want this to take up the entire page? Or you need it to be centered?

Comment: 3/4th of the page.I dont want cenered or full width

Comment: And you want to use container as opposed to container-fluid? Also, why is it inside of a form? Is that needed?

Comment: Yes I need all the formfields and containers. Because I am using it . This is the one of the field I am using it in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I think you are trying to achieve which is to show the paragraph on 1/4 of the page. If this is not what you are looking to do you can comment below and I will gladly edit to help you out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--Stylesheets-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--JS-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="grey_text text-center">Details</h2>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="form">
        <form>
          <fieldset>
              <label class="col-md-8" for="comments:">Added comments:</label>
              <div class="col-8" >
                <p>
                  Respected Sir/Madam, My name is nnnnn. I have completed my Bachelor's degree from this college in the field of Engineering. I love problem-solving and reducing the complexity of issues, this pushed me towards Software technology. I have
                  interned as a test engineer at a firm called vvvvvvvv and learned fundamental about testing. I always want to learn about new technologies and want to apply them in real life, which is why I feel I am suitable for this internship. The
                  project's link which I have worked the respective Github repository link/Google drive link can be found in my resume. I am attaching my resume, certificate, and Linkedin profile for your reference. Looking forward to hearing from you
                  soon. Thanks and regards, nnnnnnn LinkedIn profile: https://www.linkedin.com/in/nnnnnn/</p>
              </div>

          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want the paragraph to be occupied to the almost full page. So that the number of lines will be reduced and I can see other fileds without scrolling down

Comment: Ok made an edit, now the paragraph takes up 3/4 of the page.

Comment: What is the change here? is it <div class="col-8">

Comment: Correct. But I also put your entire thing inside of a row. Bootstrap grid needs to have columns inside of rows. Each row can be split up into 12 columns, so if you specify 8 ```col-8``` then you are telling it to take up 8 columns in all viewports.